# Should I set Delegate to self to use an event delegate?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

I'm learning about event delegates. The following code adds a polyline to a map view. However, it's not adding the line. Is it because I am not setting delegate?

```
var locations = new[] 
{ 
    new CLLocationCoordinate2D (13.0070069814252, 77.5551893019917), 
    new CLLocationCoordinate2D (13.0070831090451, 77.5543436352358) 
};

MKPolyline processedPolyline = MKPolyline.FromCoordinates(locations.ToArray());

map.OverlayRenderer += delegate(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
    MKPolylineRenderer polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(overlay as MKPolyline);
    polylineRenderer.LineWidth = 4.0f;
    polylineRenderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Green;
    return polylineRenderer;
};
map.AddOverlay(processedPolyline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin, C# events are often used in the place of Objective-C style delegates (though the latter option is almost always still available). Xamarin has some [documentation] about these concepts.

In any case, your code is working fine for me:

[image]

P.S. you don't need `locations.ToArray()` - just `locations` is enough as it's already an array.